# SQL Server performance with using JOINs inside views vs writing them in sprocs?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, left-join

In a database I have less than 200,000 records in a table, and in a stored procedure I am referencing a couple of views that perform several LEFT JOINs and other joins.

One of the views used contains four LEFT OUTER JOINs, another two contain several INNER JOINs just linking tables/data.

When viewing the sproc execution plan, I saw that one query was taking up 39% of the execution time.  The suggestion in green was to create a nonclustered index on two fields of the master table, which I did (already contained a clustered index, as it contains an auto-incrementing PK).

After adding this, the execution time didn't drop that much, and is currently hovering around 2.5 seconds.

Is this to be expected?

I am partial to keeping things (although maybe not normalized) in large master tables, thus eliminating the need for views/joins.

Would it be bests to refactor the db in this way, at this time?

**UPDATE**

This sproc runs through about 14 different rules to find matches.  If a match is found, content is appended to a global parameter.  Thus, to check for each rule, there is a separate query.

Instead of having 14 or so queries in the one sproc, I created separate sprocs and called them using EXEC, passing in (along with other parameters) and returning that global parameter.

I performed an execution plan with `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON`.

The first culprit (shows total subtree cost of 4.408248)

```
   SELECT @ExternalTagName = etbs.ExternalTagName, @ExternalTagID = etbs.ExternalTagID, @ExternalPixelValue = etbs.ExternalPixelValue, @TriggerAlpha = ISNULL(SUM(dbo.FindInString(etbs.TriggerValue, @DocumentUrl)), '')   FROM vw_ETBS etbs   WHERE etbs.SystemBehaviouralSegmentID = 9  -- page url contains   AND etbs.AccountContainerID = @AccountContainerID   AND etbs.IsEnabled = 1    AND etbs.TriggerValue = @TriggerAlpha   GROUP BY ExternalPixelValue, etbs.ExternalTagID, etbs.ExternalTagName     --INSERT INTO DebugTable (DebugKey, DebugValue)   --VALUES ('after sql', 'test')  79  259 1   NULL    NULL    67  NULL    63.26242    NULL    NULL    NULL    4.408248    NULL    NULL    SELECT  0   NULL
       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1016]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(6000),[ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue],0), [Expr1017]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(512),isnull([Expr1015],(0)),0))) 79  260 259 Compute Scalar  Compute Scalar  DEFINE:([Expr1016]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(6000),[ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue],0), [Expr1017]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(512),isnull([Expr1015],(0)),0))   [Expr1016]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(6000),[ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue],0), [Expr1017]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(512),isnull([Expr1015],(0)),0)    63.26242    0   6.326241E-06    3293    4.408248    [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID], [Expr1016], [Expr1017]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1015]=CASE WHEN [Expr1029]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1030] END))   79  261 260 Compute Scalar  Compute Scalar  DEFINE:([Expr1015]=CASE WHEN [Expr1029]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1030] END)  [Expr1015]=CASE WHEN [Expr1029]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1030] END   63.26242    0   0.004639106 4063    4.408242    [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue], [Expr1015]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                 |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID]) DEFINE:([Expr1029]=COUNT_BIG([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[FindInString]([Expr1019],CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(max),[@DocumentUrl],0))), [Expr1030]=SUM([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[FindInString]([Expr1019],CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(max),[@DocumentUrl],0))), [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue]=ANY([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue]))) 79  262 261 Stream Aggregate    Aggregate   GROUP BY:([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID]) [Expr1029]=COUNT_BIG([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[FindInString]([Expr1019],CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(max),[@DocumentUrl],0))), [Expr1030]=SUM([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[FindInString]([Expr1019],CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(max),[@DocumentUrl],0))), [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue]=ANY([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue])    63.26242    0   0.004639106 4063    4.408242    [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue], [Expr1029], [Expr1030]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                      |--Sort(ORDER BY:([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName] ASC, [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID] ASC))  79  263 262 Sort    Sort    ORDER BY:([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName] ASC, [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID] ASC) NULL    7679.125    0.01126126  0.311861    4125    4.403603    [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue], [Expr1019]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
                           |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[VisitorTriggeredTagID], [Expr1028]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)   79  264 263 Nested Loops    Inner Join  OUTER REFERENCES:([ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[VisitorTriggeredTagID], [Expr1028]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH   NULL    7679.125    0   0.03209874  4133    4.076795    [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagName], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[VisitorTriggeredExternalTag].[ExternalTagID], [ROTags-Shopify-Alpha].[dbo].[ExternalTagList].[ExternalPixelValue], [Expr1019]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1

SELECT @ExternalTagName = ExternalTagName, @ExternalTagID = ExternalTagID, @ExternalPixelValue = ExternalPixelValue, @TriggerNumeric = COUNT(*)
FROM vw_ETBS
WHERE SystemBehaviouralSegmentID = 10       -- direct traffic
AND AccountContainerID = @AccountContainerID    
AND vw_ETBS.IsEnabled = 1
GROUP BY ExternalPixelValue, ExternalTagID, ExternalTagName
```

vw_ETBS:

```
SELECT [lots of individual fields]
FROM    dbo.VisitorTriggeredExternalTag LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.PageVisitEvents ON dbo.VisitorTriggeredExternalTag.PageVisitEventID = dbo.PageVisitEvents.PageVisitEventID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.ExternalTagBehaviouralSegments ON dbo.VisitorTriggeredExternalTag.ExternalTagID = dbo.ExternalTagBehaviouralSegments.ExternalTagID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.ExternalTagList ON dbo.ExternalTagBehaviouralSegments.ExternalTagID = dbo.ExternalTagList.ExternalTagID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.AccountContainers ON dbo.ExternalTagList.AccountContainerID = dbo.AccountContainers.AccountContainerID
```

Comment: Do you by chance have views that call other views? Those can be dirt slow.

Comment: No views that call other views.  Only views that contain joins to tables.

Comment: Can you show us the sp? Sometimes seeing what you aredoing can give us some ideas as to where there might be issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Include SET NOCOUNT ON statement**: With every SELECT and DML statement, the SQL server returns a message that indicates the number of affected rows by that statement. This information is mostly helpful in debugging the code, but it is useless after that. By setting SET NOCOUNT ON, we can disable the feature of returning this extra information. For stored procedures that contain several statements or contain Transact-SQL loops, setting SET NOCOUNT to ON can provide a significant performance boost because network traffic is greatly reduced.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ProcName
AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Procedure code here
SELECT column1 FROM dbo.TblTable1
-- Reset SET NOCOUNT to OFF
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```

**Use schema name with object name**: The object name is qualified if used with schema name. Schema name should be used with the stored procedure name and with all objects referenced inside the stored procedure. This help in directly finding the complied plan instead of searching the objects in other possible schema before finally deciding to use a cached plan, if available. This process of searching and deciding a schema for an object leads to COMPILE lock on stored procedure and decreases the stored procedure’s performance. Therefore, always refer the objects with qualified name in the stored procedure like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable -- Preferred method
 -- Instead of
SELECT * FROM MyTable -- Avoid this method
 --And finally call the stored procedure with qualified name like:
EXEC dbo.MyProc -- Preferred method
 --Instead of
EXEC MyProc -- Avoid this method
```

**Do not use the prefix “sp_” in the stored procedure name:** If a stored procedure name begins with “SP_,” then SQL server first searches in the master database and then in the current session database. Searching in the master database causes extra overhead and even a wrong result if another stored procedure with the same name is found in master database.
Use IF EXISTS (SELECT 1) instead of (SELECT *): To check the existence of a record in another table, we uses the IF EXISTS clause. The IF EXISTS clause returns True if any value is returned from an internal statement, either a single value “1” or all columns of a record or complete recordset. The output of the internal statement is not used. Hence, to minimize the data for processing and network transferring, we should use “1” in the SELECT clause of an internal statement, as shown below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects
WHERE name = 'MyTable' AND type = 'U')
```

Use the sp_executesql stored procedure instead of the EXECUTE statement.
 The sp_executesql stored procedure supports parameters. So, using the sp_executesql stored procedure instead of the EXECUTE statement improve the re-usability of your code. The execution plan of a dynamic statement can be reused only if each and every character, including case, space, comments and parameter, is same for two statements. For example, if we execute the below batch:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Age INT
 SET @Age = 25
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.tblPerson WHERE Age = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@Age)
EXEC (@Query)
```

If we again execute the above batch using different @Age value, then the execution plan for SELECT statement created for @Age =25 would not be reused. However, if we write the above batch as given below,

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Query = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.tblPerson WHERE Age = @Age'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query, N'@Age int', @Age = 25
```

the compiled plan of this SELECT statement will be reused for different value of @Age parameter. The reuse of the existing complied plan will result in improved performance.
Try to avoid using SQL Server cursors whenever possible: Cursor uses a lot of resources for overhead processing to maintain current record position in a recordset and this decreases the performance. If we need to process records one-by-one in a loop, then we should use the WHILE clause. Wherever possible, we should replace the cursor-based approach with SET-based approach. Because the SQL Server engine is designed and optimized to perform SET-based operation very fast. Again, please note cursor is also a kind of WHILE Loop.

**Keep the Transaction as short as possible**: The length of transaction affects blocking and deadlocking. Exclusive lock is not released until the end of transaction. In higher isolation level, the shared locks are also aged with transaction. Therefore, lengthy transaction means locks for longer time and locks for longer time turns into blocking. In some cases, blocking also converts into deadlocks. So, for faster execution and less blocking, the transaction should be kept as short as possible.
Use TRY-Catch for error handling: Prior to SQL server 2005 version code for error handling, there was a big portion of actual code because an error check statement was written after every t-sql statement. More code always consumes more resources and time. In SQL Server 2005, a new simple way is introduced for the same purpose. The syntax is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRY
--Your t-sql code goes here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--Your error handling code goes here
END CATCH
```

For More info refer this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) U will get better idea.

Comment: There's no indications that sp_ or no count are in any way involved with the performance issues being talked about above.

Answer (score 2):

Views, unless they're indexed views (which you have to follow a lot of rules both to define and to make use of) are analogous to macros in other programming languages - they're effectively expanded out into the query that makes use of them, and then the entire query is optimized at that point.

As such, views are not in any way "about" performance - all they generally provide is a short-hand for referring to a query (they may be hiding a complex query, or implementing specialized rules such as security also).

I'd continue examining the execution plans, and keep working away at the most expensive portions of the query, until the execution time is acceptable for you - I have no idea whether 2.5 seconds is "fast enough" in your current situation, and you *do* need to define what the acceptable performance is before pursuing optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world, joining one view to another would not affect your performance at all. Unfortunately, in the world we live in, it's a problem. Basically, the more objects and joins you throw at the optimizer, the more work it has to do in a limited amount of time, the more likely you'll get a timeout which results in a sub-optimal plan. So, in general, instead of joining one view to another, it's better to just rewrite the query so that you're only referencing the information you need, making the work easier for the optimizer.

As far as putting everything in big tables instead of normalizing the data, depending on your situation, this can perform better. But, it can also perform worse. Instead of small data sets discretely stored with lots of information on a single page, you're cramming very large data sets onto a page, so that there are very few rows per page. No matter what, you have to read the page, so if you're going for a single row of information, you may see the same, or even less performance by eliminating joins. But, when you see multiple seeks or scans performance can degrade severely over normalized data.

If you're using a relational database management system, I'd strongly recommend surrendering to the concepts of relational data managment. Normalize the structures, enforce primary keys, enforce foreign keys, work with the system as it's designed and you'll reap benefits. Most problems come about when people stop treating the RDBMS as that and instead try to treat it like a file store or one of the NoSQL systems (which are really good at what they do, but you have to need what they do for them to work well, I've also seen people using the NoSQL databases like an RDBMS and then complaining that they don't work right...).

Answer (score 0):

Only join on indexed columns, rebuild indexes on all tables in the query(or index defrag them), especially on the tables you are joining and getting this bad performance.

After maintaining your indexes, run "UPDATE STATISTICS tableName" preferably "WITH FULLSCAN" to get the best samples, but specifying "WITH SAMPLE 20 PERCENT" or any large sample size gives you better stats than using the default. Also, if you opt to rebuild all indexes, then you can save time by also adding "COLUMNS", to only regenerate column stats, as rebuilding indexes already gives you a perfect sampling of index statistics.
So the optimal statement would be "UPDATE STATISTICS tableName WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS"

Also, I second what has already been said about writing the whole query using only actual tables instead of views, unless the views are indexed in your favor. Also, you should only specify the columns you will actually use in the SELECT statement, rather than using SELECT *. That gives the optimizer a chance  to do less work, perhaps even skip reading clustered indexes in some of the tables, if you happen to have an index that covers all you need from that table.

If making the changes I suggested doesn't give you better performance and you are not suffering from blocking then I think we need to look at your query plan to get a better view of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

A view is a virtual table that consists of columns from one or more tables. You cannot filter the records actually from this technique. All the matched/Unmatched records will come up in your Result Set depending upon your Join(Inner/Left).

So , basically while using a view you will have to wait for the execution until all records gets stored in the RAM...

On the other hand, Stored Procedure gives you the option for input Parameters to filter the query..

There are two ways to get the result set quickly from the stored procedure, depending upon the number of records present in the particular table...

**Case 1**

```
Select Column1, Column2 From LargeTable T1
Inner Join SmallTable T2 on T2.Id = T1.Id
Where T1.ID = 1;
```

**Case 2**

```
Select Column1, Column2 From
(
    Select Column1, Column2, ID From LargeTable Where ID = 1
)K
Inner Join SmallTable T2 on T2.ID = K.ID
```

Check the differences...Hope this will help you to optimize it ...

Comment: This is a good suggestion - essentially taking the logic out of the views and just adding them to the sproc.  So the question is, in general, will performance increase taking the JOINing logic out of a view, and use it in your sproc instead?  You're still creating the joins, etc., so would creating that non-normalized master table render better performance?

Comment: check the join in case of 2... This will have small index, so execution will be fastest.